# Displaying the list which have two common elements in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists as follows.

```
temp=[[1,2,3],[0,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,4,5],[0,4,5]]
```

I want to display all the lists which have the second and the third element to be common. In th above example, the result should be `[[1,2,3],[0,2,3],[1,4,5],[0,4,5]]`

Thank you

Comment: What you've tried so far? Where did you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
>>> ends = [i[1:] for i in temp]
>>> print ends
[[2, 3], [2, 3], [5, 6], [4, 5], [4, 5]]

>>> result = [i for i in temp if ends.count(i[1:]) > 1]
>>> print result
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [0, 4, 5]]
```

For this solution I used list comprehensions, you can read about them here:
http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: If you found this solution solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer(the tick mark beside the votes)

Answer (score 0):

```
res = []
for idx, i in enumerate(temp):
    for jdx, j in enumerate(temp):
        if i[1]==j[1] and i[2]==j[2] and jdx != idx:
            res.append(i)
```